# How to pass parameter to guard?

Tags: angular, typescript, web, angular-ui-router, angular-router-guards

I have project-based angular 12.

I need to secure a route based on a parameter which is colled token:

```
 export const authenticationRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'reset-password/token/:token',
    component: ResetPasswordShellComponent,
    canActivate: [ResetPasswordGuard]
  }
];
```

ResetPasswordGuard is a guard that makes calls to web service and should send token value which is part of the path:

```
path: 'reset-password/token/:token'
```

My question is there any way to pass token value from the path to guard(ResetPasswordGuard) so it will be sent to the web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we implement the interface `CanActiavte` on `ResetPasswordGuard`, the function `canActivate` takes 2 parameters, first of which is `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`...

```ts
canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        // your  logic goes here
        console.log('[ResetPasswordGuard]', next.params); // <-- This should print {token: 'somevalue'}
        ....
        ....
    }
```

So one can easily read path parameters from it using...

```ts
const tokenInPath = next.params.token || ''
```

Using an `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` one has access to the whole data in the URL. `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` also provides `Observable` interfaces for reading/receiving intended information(path params, query params etc...).

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***